# How to change default login logic of laravel?

Tags: laravel

Basically I want to use old database for login using jwt. Basically I want to use old database for login using jwt. I have a old project which used mdf and custom hashing fucntion. Now I want an api authentication using jwt but how to authenticate with old hashing ?

Comment: Please show [mre]

Answer (score 0):

For API authentication, [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum) is a good place to start. If that doesn't meet your requirements, check out [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport).